# Not printing first Element of Array

Tags: arrays, c

i am writing a program for "The C Programming Language" - Exercise 1-17. Depsite not having turned a few things into custom functions, i have the problem that my code is not printing or writing the first element of the Array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxCharacters 1000
#define printCondition 10 // the line will only be printed if it is >= printCondition


//int getLine()

int main()
{
    int c;
    int l = 0; //length of the line in numbers
    int i = 0;

    char lastLine[maxCharacters];
    
    while(getchar() != EOF)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < maxCharacters - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n'; i++)
            lastLine[i] = c;
        
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            lastLine[i] = c;
            ++i;
        }
        
        lastLine[i] = '\0';
        
        
        if (i > printCondition)
        {
            printf("%s", lastLine);
        }
        
        else
            printf("zu kurz\n");
    }
}
```

thx guys

Comment: `while(getchar() != EOF)` reads one character, and throws it away. So the first character of each line is not stored in the array.

Comment: thank you. Can u explain why it does behave like that? thx

edit: i changed the line to while(c =! EOF) . Now it works fine

Comment: Note `while(c != EOF)` is undefined behaviour if `c` is not initialised.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase that. `while(getchar() != EOF)` reads one character, and since the code doesn't store that character in a variable, the code has no way to put that character in the array.

Comment: thx. that is a very understandable explanation